# JOptionPane. Program does not display the error message

Tags: java, string, swing, try-catch, joptionpane

I have this code that asks for a username and password. Just a simple JOptionPane. The program should ask an input and if the user did not write any input in the username, it should display an error message and displays the same, previous dialog box asking for a username. However, it does not work that way. Even though I do not input anything, it still proceed to the password dialog box. Please do check my logic, I might have been a bit confused; and is there also a way to check if the input in the `showInputDialog` is a string? somewhat like the `NumberFormatException` for integers? The Exception on catch method, does not work either. :) Thanks in advance.

```
public class SwingExercise {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String name = null;
    boolean input = true;

    try {
        while (input) {
            while (name == null) {
                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter username:");
                if (name == null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No input.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            String pw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter password:");
            input = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }


}
```

Comment: You are Most Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter password:");`  Use a [`JPasswordField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) to get a password.  See [How to Use Password Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) for more details.

Comment: @Layne : See I had modified your code, and do look at what Andrew Thompson, has to say, a very genuine point he made :-)

Comment: @GagandeepBali, yeap, saw your code. Thank you very much :D and yea, thanks for the info Andrew Thompson :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
if(name == null || name.equals("")) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No input.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   name = null;
}
```

and regarding this question:

> is there also a way to check if the input in the showInputDialog is a string?

`showInputDialog()` returns String, even numbers, it reads them as String.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! :) Your code did work :D However, what if I wanted just a name and no numbers, how would I have that condition?

Comment: @Layne : Than you should use a `JDialog`, add one `JTextField` to it and to this `JTextField` add `DocumentListener` to allow only Alphabets and no numbers :-) Or else check the `name` String for any numbers by going through each index of the `name` String if it returns true, flag it and show ERROR.

Comment: @GagandeepBali, I'm sorry but how do you check the `name` String through each index? I'm just a newbie, please do bear with me.

Comment: @Layne : This is not the right place to place code, But check this out `public class CharacterTest
{
 public static void main(String... args)
 {
  String text = "MyName!@hasadigit5";
  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
  {
   if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i)))
   {
    System.out.println("Sorry Invalid Input as : " + text.charAt(i));
    // Put your flag and use that in conditions.
    break;
   } 
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 2):

try declaring

```
String name = "";
```

instead of

```
String name = null;
```

and then check if the string name is empty in the loop condition and in the if condition.

```
while (name.equals(""))
```

...

```
if (name.equals(""))
```

That's because the method showInputDialog returns an String, and the correct way to compare a String is using objectString.equals(anotherObjectString), you were comparing a String returned from showInputDialog with null, wich always return false.

Comment: Actually, if you click `Cancel` on the `showInputDialog(...)` it will return a null `String` I guess. So null should be tested inside the condition, but +1 for testing for "" (EMPTY String) :-)

Comment: I do have a problem with the cancel button. Whenever I click it, it displays the error message on my catch method. How do I make the cancel button terminate the program?

Comment: Don't know which `showInputMessage(...)` is causing the problem :-) , but if you wanted to terminate the program, do this `if (password == null) System.exit(0);`, this will terminate the whole program.

Comment: Still the same, it displays the error message that is in my catch method, then it terminates. How do I get to terminate it by using the cancel button without displaying the error message?

Comment: you should always compare first if the String is null an then if the string is empty.
Example:
in the loop:
while (name == null || name.equals(""))
in the if:
if (name == null || name.equals(""))  

If it was like (name.equals("") || name == null) and the name is null, it will raise a NullPointerException, because it will first attempt to invoke the equals method from a null object, raising the exception that will be catched in you catch block